# Kubelete fails with code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have setup K8S on fedora 37, following a

```
Kubeadmi init
```

seems images are pulled and things seemed correct. However, when I try

```
Kubectl cluster-info

0406 11:58:52.440579 704658 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://192.168.1.48:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 192.168.1.48:6443: connect: connection refused E0406 11:58:52.441106 704658 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://192.168.1.48:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 192.168.1.48:6443: connect: connection refused E0406 11:58:52.442602 704658 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://192.168.1.48:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 192.168.1.48:6443: connect: connection refused E0406 11:58:52.444035 704658 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://192.168.1.48:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 192.168.1.48:6443: connect: connection refused E0406 11:58:52.445543 704658 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://192.168.1.48:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 192.168.1.48:6443: connect: connection refused
```

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.

after digging, I discovered thet kubelet service is not running, when I check its status I see

> Process: 662008 ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS
> $KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS
> (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE) Main PID: 662008 (code=exited,
> status=1/FAILURE)

I issue the command

```
sudo journalctl -xeu kubelet
```

I find some strange indication regarding swapp

> Apr 06 11:46:05 puppetmaster29 kubelet[604092]: I0406 11:46:05.929992
> 604092 server.go:198] "--pod-infra-container-image will not be pruned
> by the image garbage collector in kubelet and should> Apr 06 11:46:05
> puppetmaster29 kubelet[604092]: Flag --pod-infra-container-image has
> been deprecated, will be removed in 1.27. Image garbage collector will
> get sandbox image information from CR> Apr 06 11:46:05 puppetmaster29
> kubelet[604092]: I0406 11:46:05.959288 604092 server.go:412] "Kubelet
> version" kubeletVersion="v1.26.3" Apr 06 11:46:05 puppetmaster29
> kubelet[604092]: I0406 11:46:05.959563 604092 server.go:414] "Golang
> settings" GOGC="" GOMAXPROCS="" GOTRACEBACK="" Apr 06 11:46:05
> puppetmaster29 kubelet[604092]: I0406 11:46:05.960072 604092
> server.go:836] "Client rotation is on, will bootstrap in background"
> Apr 06 11:46:05 puppetmaster29 kubelet[604092]: I0406 11:46:05.962910
> 604092 certificate_store.go:130] Loading cert/key pair from
> "/var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem". Apr 06 11:46:05
> puppetmaster29 kubelet[604092]: I0406 11:46:05.964710 604092
> dynamic_cafile_content.go:157] "Starting controller"
> name="client-ca-bundle::/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt" Apr 06 11:46:05
> puppetmaster29 kubelet[604092]: I0406 11:46:05.972921 604092
> server.go:659] "--cgroups-per-qos enabled, but --cgroup-root was not
> specified. defaulting to /" Apr 06 11:46:05 puppetmaster29
> kubelet[604092]: E0406 11:46:05.973293 604092 run.go:74] "command
> failed" err="failed to run Kubelet: running with swap on is not
> supported, please disable swap!> Apr 06 11:46:05 puppetmaster29
> systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Main process exited, code=exited,
> status=1/FAILURE ░░ Subject: Unit process exited ░░ Defined-By:
> systemd ░░ Support:
> https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel ░░ ░░ An
> ExecStart= process belonging to unit kubelet.service has exited. ░░ ░░
> The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.

I have executed

```
sudo swappoff -a
```

a couple of times and even commented it inside the fstab file as follows

```
/dev/mapper/fedora-root /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=50a98c60-a467-4c60-9fcb-e394c74043a7 /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
# /dev/mapper/fedora-swap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
So not really know what to do or how to solve this, thanks for your help
```

Comment: (a) so after commenting out the swap, you rebooted? (b) kind of related to that, after issuing the swapoff you did `systemctl restart kubelet.service`?

Comment: Yes Sir, rebooted 2 times and restarted the kubelet service but always same thing

Comment: I even deleted the swap partition, rebooted, getting the exact same error in the log " command failed" err="failed to run Kubelet: running with swap on is not supported, please disable"

Comment: Welp, here is where kubernetes being open source really shines; you can [see what that check is doing](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes@v1.26.3/-/blob/pkg/kubelet/cm/container_manager_linux.go?L210-211) and investigate for yourself. They also offer a [`--fail-swap-on=false`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/54542#issuecomment-565223605) if you want to roll the dice

Comment: sorry but I have never used GO language